# Git Commit Fatal Error: fsync error on '.git/objects/...': Bad file descriptor

Tags: git, git-commit

Get error when commit changes:

Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
fatal: fsync error on '.git/objects/92/tmp_obj_defDi8': Bad file descriptor

But only in a specific directory. If I clone this Repo in a different directory, I can commit changes without getting an error.

This is just a normal directory. If I go up a folder, it also works without problems. The only thing i now, someday I got another error message on a commit: "antoher git process has a lockfile on this repo" or something like that.

Comment: What is special about this directory? Network filesystem? Automatic synchronization (like GDrive)?

Comment: Nothing like that. Just a normal directory.

If I go up a folder, it also works without problems.

The only thing i now, someday I get another error message on a commit: "antoher git process has a lockfile on this repo" or something like that.

Comment: Your disk could be failing

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error message and every time i try to commit a new file in .git\objects\73\ was created. The new file was in the error message like "tmp_obj_5K82YN".

I have a VPN to Azure DevOps and multiple developer VMs not connected to the VPN. The project is on a network share which is connected to all machines with the same letter.

Solution for me was to local commit on the VM, close the project on the VM, open the project on the machine with VPN and push the commit from there.